# How does Facebook's Like button iframe expand with a popover and not screw everything else up?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, iframe

When you click FB's Like button on an non-FB site, a popup shows up that asks you to write a message. How do they do this? It looks like they expand the iframe somehow, but I can't figure out how to doesn't screw everything else up. Thanks.

Try it (this won't work if you don't have FB): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ Click "Like" to see popover

Comment: offhand my first guess is they change the z-index

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is curious - its an iframe absolutely positioned that changes sizes in a div.